# fine-uploader example traditional build

Tags: fine-uploader

So, I'm trying to evaluate fine-uploader.  I decided to go to the download page, but it wants you to purchase a license, but I don't want to do that until after I've evaluated it.  So, I went to github and downloaded the master zip for it and unzipped.  My question is now what?  The so-called "step-by-step" are not step-by-step.  Am I supposed to build something?  The documentation states I just need to include one file....which file?  In the demos, for traditional use, i see it includes  fineuploader-{VERSION}.js, but I see no file that even starts with "fineuploader" in the subdirectory of "client/js/*".

Am I just missing the documentation for this completely?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the first line missing "{" in package.json, after cloned fineuploader from github.

Comment: We've updated the build instructions at http://docs.fineuploader.com/contributing.html.  All should be well now.

Comment: The build process has changed for the better. See my most recent answer.

Answer (score 14):

Following Bjørn Børresen's answer, the official documentation (which is severely lacking) and some troubleshooting, I was successfull on Ubuntu 13.10 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install npm git 
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
sudo npm install -g bower
git clone https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader.git
cd fine-uploader
npm install http://github.com/e-jigsaw/grunt/tarball/fix-underscore-string-version
bower install
sudo npm install -g
npm install grunt
npm install
grunt package
```

Comment: if git, grunt, bower and so on already installed, the only requiered commands are `git clone git@github.com:Widen/fine-uploader.git`, `cd fine-uploader`, `bower install`, `npm install`, `grunt package`

Comment: The build process has changed for the better. See my most recent answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need git, NPM, Grunt & Bower.

Assuming you have git, if not install it. Then navigate to http://nodejs.org/ and INSTALL NodeJS.

From the command line:

- npm install -g grunt-cli
- npm install -g bower
- git clone git@github.com:Widen/fine-uploader.git
- cd fine-uploader
- bower install
- npm install -g
- grunt

Comment: The build process has changed for the better. See my most recent answer.

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps that worked for me on Windows 7:

**I. Install Prereqs (should only be necessary the first time)**

1. [Install node.js on windows if you haven't already](http://nodejs.org/).
2. Ensure npm has been added to your PATH variable (as of this writing, node.js puts this in during install):

   `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`
3. [Install git on windows if you haven't already](http://git-scm.com/).
4. Ensure the git commands have been added to your PATH variable (as of this writing the git install *does not* add these):

   `C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`
5. Open command prompt.
6. Install grunt globally:

   `npm install -g grunt`
7. Install grunt-cli globally:

   `npm install -g grunt-cli`
8. Clone the repo if you haven't already:

   `git clone git://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader`
9. Change command prompt directory to repo location (most likely at %USERPROFILE%\fine-uploader).
10. Install dependencies (if you want the dependencies installed
    globally add a `-g` below but it is not necessary):

    `npm install`

**II. Build and Package**

1. Open command prompt at the repo location (i.e. %USERPROFILE%\fine-uploader)
2. Pull latest, if necessary:

   `git pull`
3. package it up:

   `grunt package`

This should result in the files being added to the _dist folder in your repo.

Comment: The build process has changed for the better. See my most recent answer.

Answer (score 3):

The build and distribution methods have changed quite a bit over the past couple years. As of Fine Uploader 5.11, you have the following options:

### Download [Fine Uploader from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fine-uploader)

`npm install fine-uploader`

### Download Fine Uploader from the project's home page

...at http://fineuploader.com/customize

### Build Fine Uploader yourself from the GitHub repo

1. `git clone https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader.git`
2. `cd fine-uploader`
3. `npm install`
4. `make build`

The ["contribute code" section in the README](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader#contribute-code) contains even more details.